# How to make numbering navigation after break; in PHP?

Tags: php

Hi all I have searching for method but not luck. Help me I want to make numbering navigation. Here is my code:

```
        <ul>
            <?php
            $kw = file_get_contents('keywords.txt');
            $kw = explode("\n", $kw);
            asort($kw);
            $i = 0;
            foreach($kw as $k) {
            if($i==30) { break; }
            ?>
                <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $domain.'/'.clean($k);?>"><?php echo ucwords($k);?></a>
                </li>
            <?php $i++; } ?>
        </ul>
```

The above code just displayed 30 result from 1500 keyword I have. I want to make Page Numbering navigation also shorting A-Z. So user can Short Keyword by Alphabetic above it and page numbering after it.

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/ would help.

Comment: Thanks for respond. Could you please tell me how to make it? I don't know how to insert the code. please give me the complete codes :D

Comment: The tutorial is present on the site i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Datatables.

**Table**

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>KeyWord</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($kw as $k) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $domain.'/'.clean($k);?>"><?php echo ucwords($k);?></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

Do include the proper plugin files for js & css. from - [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks for help sgt BOSE! I have try your code but not success I got error and blank page.

Comment: check the console and turn on the error reporting. See what error you are getting.

Comment: I have update above what error I get. thanks for help!